# How to integrate any AndroidX SDK in Non AndroidX app

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, android-10.0, jobintentservice

I have migrated my Android Library Project (SDK) to AndroidX and it is using `implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0'` dependency. After integrating this SDK in a Non AndroidX app, my SDK is crashing with following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/core/app/JobIntentService;
        at com.xyz.services.sdk.d.a(Unknown Source) 
        at com.xyz.services.sdk.d$1$1.run(Unknown Source) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Few of my SDK users have not migrated to AndroidX yet but I want them to use the latest version of my Android Library which has AndroidX. I have not yet released my library with androidx changes, How can I support an AndroidX Library in a Non AndroidX app?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I support an AndroidX Library in a Non AndroidX app?

AFAIK that's not possible

End user's have only two choices

- Migrate their app to `AndroidX`.
- Downgrade the library version